# having trouble understanding the proof of regular expression identities $(u + v)^* = (u^*v)^*u^*$

Tags: regular-languages, regular-expressions, proof-techniques

I am having trouble understanding the proof given below:

> \begin{align}
> (u \cup v)^* &= (u^* \cup v)^* \\ &= u^*(u \cup v)^* = (u\cup vu^*)^* \\ &= (u^*v^*)^* = u^*(vu^*)^* \\ &= (u^*v)^*u^*
> \end{align}

In more detail, why does $(u + v)^* = (u^* + v)^*$ hold? Why can we just put a star on $u$? Is it a property?

Also, why can we extract the $u^*$ from the $(u^* + v)^*$ and then put it after $v$?
Why can the $+$ be eliminated from $(u + vu^*)^*$ to $(u^*v^*)^*$?

Comment: The proof presumably uses some equational theory of regular expressions. Such equational theories are useless if you do not believe the axioms.

Comment: Stated differently, this proof seems to be intended as a demonstration of some equational theory of regular expressions. You seem to be looking for a different type of proof. Therefore I suggest you ignore this proof, and attempt to prove the equivalence from first principles.

Answer (score 3):

How does one prove that two regular expressions represent the same language? One approach is using *axiomatizations of the equational theory of regular expressions*.

The equational theory of regular expressions consists of all statements $\alpha = \beta$ where $\alpha,\beta$ represent two equivalent regular expressions. In this context, an axiom is an equational identity such as $u \cup v = v \cup u$. Each such axiom is really an axiom scheme: you can substitute anything you want for $u$ and $v$. Furthermore, you can use the principle of substitution of equals by equals to apply this axiom in a larger context, for example deducing that $(u \cup v)^* = (v \cup u)^*$.

When designing an axiom system, we are looking for two properties: *soundness* and *completeness*. Soundness means that all the axiomatic identities are in fact true. Which axioms are true could depend on the alphabet: for example, if the alphabet is unary, then $uv = vu$, but this is not true over larger alphabets. Completeness means that if $\alpha = \beta$ then this can be proved in the system. Salomaa constructed two complete axiom systems in his classic paper [Two Complete Axiom Systems for the Algebra of Regular Events](https://doi-org.ezlibrary.technion.ac.il/10.1145/321312.321326).

The proof you are quoting seems to make use of some axiom system, whose axioms you seem not to believe. The proof is probably intended as a demonstration of the axiom system. The description of the axiom system should be accompanied by a soundness proof of the axioms. This suggests one course of action for you — looking up the description of the axiom system, and the proofs of the relevant axioms. Another course of action is to look for a different proof of the entire identity from first principles.

Answer (score 2):

$(u+v)^*$ denotes an arbitrary string made of $u$'s and $v$'s, which is the same as $(u^*+v)^*$ or $(u+v^*)^*$ or $(u^*+v^*)^*$, as any character can be repeated anyway.

Now you can freely prepend or append the expression with $u^*$ or $v^*$ or another $(u+v)^*$, outside the parenthesis, or even inside (in any case the $^*$ terms can vanish, otherwise they may contribute *some part* of the string).

You will also agree that $u^*v^*$ is a superset of $u+v$, so that $(u^*v^*)^*=(u+v)^*$.

Finally, you can split a string in all pieces that start/end in a single $u$ or $v$ and complete with extra $v$'s or $u$'s before or after.

E.g. $uuvvvvuvuuuvuvuvuuvuvuvuv=uu\ v\ v\ v\ vu\ vuuu\ vu\ vu\ vuu\ vu\ vu\ v=u^*(vu^*)^*$.